# Lodash: Group and restructure the json object using Lodash

Tags: lodash

How can i group and restructure the json object using lodash.
Have a json object like this

```
var data = [
  {
    "Type": "W",
    "Id": 1,
    "Employee_Role_Desc": null,
    "Employee_Role_Id": 1,
    "StartDateTime": "2017-06-15T09:00:00",
    "EndDateTime": "2017-06-15T12:30:00",
    "Alert": null
  },
   {
    "Type": "W",
    "Id": 1,
    "Employee_Role_Desc": null,
    "Employee_Role_Id": 1,
    "StartDateTime": "2017-06-15T09:00:00",
    "EndDateTime": "2017-06-15T12:30:00",
    "Alert": null
  }, {
    "Type": "W",
    "Id": 1,
    "Employee_Role_Desc": null,
    "Employee_Role_Id": 3,
    "StartDateTime": "2017-06-15T09:00:00",
    "EndDateTime": "2017-06-15T12:30:00",
    "Alert": null
  }
]
```

Want to group t like this.

```
{
          "Role_Id": 1,
          "Date": "2017-06-15T05:12:22.9577063-05:00",
          "**Blocks**": [
            {
              "StartDateTime": "2017-06-15T05:12:22.9586499-05:00",
              "EndDateTime": "2017-06-15T05:12:22.9586499-05:00"
            },
            {
              "StartDateTime": "2017-06-15T05:12:22.9586499-05:00",
              "EndDateTime": "2017-06-15T05:12:22.9586499-05:00"
            }
          ]
        }
```

Group it by Employee_Role_Id and each StartDateTime and EndDateTime should be in a **Blocks** object
"Role_Id" in the result should be the "Employee_Role_Id" in resultant object.

Comment: should the item with `"Employee_Role_Id": 3` be ignored?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest No.That also needed

Comment: how about pure JS solution?

Comment: Have first group it by Employee_Role_Id. Then pick only needed field. But how to put inside those inside Blocks key?

Comment: If it have a simple lodash trick then that will be better :)

Comment: where does `"Date": "2017-06-15T05:12:22.9577063-05:00"` come from?

Comment: pick the date only part from start/end date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using `_.groupBy()`, and `_.map()` in a chain:

```js
const data = [{"Type":"W","Id":1,"Employee_Role_Desc":null,"Employee_Role_Id":1,"StartDateTime":"2017-06-15T09:00:00","EndDateTime":"2017-06-15T12:30:00","Alert":null},{"Type":"W","Id":1,"Employee_Role_Desc":null,"Employee_Role_Id":1,"StartDateTime":"2017-06-15T09:00:00","EndDateTime":"2017-06-15T12:30:00","Alert":null},{"Type":"W","Id":1,"Employee_Role_Desc":null,"Employee_Role_Id":3,"StartDateTime":"2017-06-15T09:00:00","EndDateTime":"2017-06-15T12:30:00","Alert":null}];

const result = _(data)
  .groupBy('Employee_Role_Id') // group the items
  .map((group, Role_Id) => ({ // map the groups to new objects
    Role_Id,
    Date: group[0].StartDateTime,
    Blocks: group.map(({ StartDateTime, EndDateTime }) => ({ // extract the dates from the groups
      StartDateTime, 
      EndDateTime
    }))
  }))
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```